# iptables can drop traffic but cannot redirect

Tags: iptables, nat

Suppose that TCP packets are sent to destination ip (dest_ip) and can be dropped by the following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d dest_ip -p tcp -j DROP
```

But when I try to redirect the packet using iptables NAT to a different ip (diff_ip), the packet still arrives at the old destination (dest_ip):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d dest_ip -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination diff_ip
```

There is something about iptables that I don't quite understand here, as I am expecting the packet to no longer reach the dest_ip. Can someone please explain why this is so? Thanks.

Additional info that may be relevant:
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is already set to 1
ifconfig shows two interfaces: eth0 and lo; dest_ip is on eth0 and diff_ip is a remote ip

UPDATE 1: further tests using telnet

A listener using socat is established on 12800 to receive telnet message:

```
socat -u TCP-LISTEN:12800,reuseaddr,keepalive,reuseaddr OPEN:/tmp/output.txt,creat,append
```

Telnet connection is made with random messages:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 12800
```

1) test using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12800 -j DROP
```

result: all messages from telnet are dropped as confirmed by the counter:

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   120 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:12800
```

2) test using:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 12800 -j DNAT --to-destination remote_ip
```

result: all message arrives at port 12800 without being redirected, which is confirmed by the counter:

```
iptables -L PREROUTING -t nat -v -n

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:12800 to:remote_ip
```

UPDATE 2:
further test using telnet (see above) but with iptables rules on the OUTPUT chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 12800 -j DNAT --to-destination remote_ip
```

result: all messages are successfully redirected as confirmed by the counter:

```
iptables -L OUTPUT -t nat -v -n

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   180 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:12800 to:remote_ip
```

This is starting to make sense since telnet is a local process and its output should directly go into the OUTPUT chain. However, this raises another question: according to update 1, telnet messages can also be dropped in the INPUT chain, so how exactly are the packets travelling? OUTPUT -> INPUT?

Comment: Any previous rules in PREROUTING which match these packets?

Comment: No, there are no other rules. Those are the only two.

Comment: Do you test this with new connections (TCP SYN packets)? You may check with tcpdump. Existing connections are not affected by PREROUTING.

Comment: This is what I am doing: I use Firefox to visit a specific site and I monitor where the returning packets are going to (ie. dest_ip). Then I try to re-direct the returning packets using DNAT as shown above. This apparently doesn't work as Firefox still displayed the page successfully. Based on what you said, perhaps, it is because this is an existing connection since Firefox already established a connection before receiving the returning packets?

Comment: Exactly. I just say: HTTP keep alive. You should try e.g. telnet instead (any program that exists after the test will do).

Comment: `try iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING -v -n` to see weather your rule is beeing used (check the counter) when you try. Also you could check that your traffic don't get stuck in any other rule eg OUTPUT or FORWARD. I seem to recollect having had similar trouble just because I dropped the package in another chain...

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I will try your methods and see if they provide further clues to this issue.

Comment: @PetterH Stucked traffic wouldn't "still arrive at the old destination", of course.

Comment: OK. I just tested this thing with telnet and the result is just as weird. Used socat to listen on localhost port 12800 and then telnet to the port. Some random message is passed on. For the command: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12800 -j DROP, no message is recorded and iptables counter showed that all packets are dropped. However, with command: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 12800 -j DNAT --to-destination remote_ip, all messages can still arrive at the old port and iptables counter showed that none of the packets are redirected by the rule...now i am really confused!

Comment: Could we see the whole of both rulesets, please, with `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -L -n -v -t nat`?  You'll probably want to edit those data into the question.

Comment: `iptables -L -n -v` is a command. He didn't want you to paste the command in the question, he wanted you to show us what happens when you type it.

Comment: please see updates with new info

Answer (score 0):

All your tests have pointed out something that you should have figured out. When dealing with Netfilter/iptables, you cannot successfully build your rules without having the [packet flow](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) in mind.

As you can see, a local process never go though the `PREROUTING` chain but only `OUTPUT` and `POSTROUTING`. This is why your `telnet` process is redirected when you place your rule in `OUTPUT` but not when you put it in `PREROTUING`. However, this rule is right for an external packet traversing your machine.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Although telnet is a local process and its packets can be manipulated in the OUTPUT chain, this still doesn't explain the initial question that an external packet coming into the machine can be dropped in the INPUT chain but cannot be re-directed in the PREROUTING chain.